# Trying to learn Android dev via old tutorials, but latest Android Studio includes Compose instead of AppCompatActivity(). How do I turn off Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Android Dev, but not a new programmer. Trying to learn via old tutorial material I had collected over the years, only to find that the Android world has moved on to new fangled stuff like JetPack and Compose. I learn by doing, and thought I'd grind through old stuff first before moving up to Compose, but the new Android Studio (Giraffe) doesn't seem to allow me to turn off the Compose stuff - e.g. the default MainActivity.kt always gives me @Composable and @Preview. All I want is to have Studio give me class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() and setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) so that I can follow along the old codes.

How do I do this? Or is attempting to install an old version of Studio alongside Giraffe the only way?

Nothing in Google seemed to help (could be me and my lack of Google kungfu). I tried to go to Settings and search of 'androidx' (turned off Live Templates under Settings > Editor) and 'jetpack' (turned off the JetPack Compose plugin). Still creates the @Compose functions in MainActivity.kt.

Comment: First Of All, You don't need to turn off the ```compose```. If you really want to learn android ```XML``` (View Based System) then you can create a new Project with the New Empty Activity Option On ```Android Studio Wizard.``` See Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkSiS.png

Comment: Hey there Chirag, thank you so much for your answer! This was 100% what I was looking for, concise and to the point! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newer versions of Android Studio (including Giraffe) still offer View-type project options when creating new projects.

Go to `File > New > New Project...` and select any of the new project templates that contain "Views" in their name on the first step of the New Project wizard.

"Views" new project template options in Android Studio Giraffe Patch 1 are:

1. Basic **Views** Activity
2. Bottom Navigation **Views** Activity
3. Empty **Views** Activity
4. Navigation Drawer **Views** Activity
5. Responsive **Views** Activity

This is how they look like
[image]

As an example, picking Basic Views Activity, will create a

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

and two fragments called `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` (along with some other required project structure, that includes files related to the build, resource files, AndroidManifest...)

This template also uses [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) in these three classes.

Picking Empty Views Activity will create just the project structure and the `MainActivity` without view binding

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Also note that if your older tutorials are using Groovy DSL as a Build configuration language (the DSL language used inside `build.gradle` files), then you might want to choose that option on the 2nd step of the New Project wizard.

[image]

I would suggest you find up-to-date Views tutorials so that you will not end up learning deprecated SDKs/APIs (unless you are maintaining an old codebase that still contains a lot of deprecated calls).

The Android documentation site also has Views tutorials and codelabs, which are also updated over time. They are a good learning resource, because in addition to explaining the code, they also focus on the Android Studio functionalities. The first chapter of a codelab is usually about setting up a new project, which guides you through the required steps to set it up correctly (for the codelab).

Comment: Hey there Ma3x, this was exactly what I was looking for, and I appreciated the detailed breakdown of the answer - now I know what I was looking for is called Views. Google's website has parts which hasn't yet updated to JetPack and Compose, so for some of their tutorials at the fringes they were still teaching Views, but there was a gap on how to get to Views from the latest versions of Studio.

Thank you once again! My journey continues!